# Pressing enter it refreshes the page with a4j:commandButton

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I've got this below:

```
<a4j:form>
 <h:inputText id="name" value="#{someBean.item.name}" styleClass="medium-field" onclick="if (this.value == 'Name') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Name'" />
 <a4j:commandButton action="#{someBean.find}" styleClass="bt-find" reRender="someFields"/>
</a4j:form>
```

When I type something on name and press Enter, it refreshes the page and does not bring me any results.
If I change it to h:commandButton it works properly. Do you guys have any idea how can I make it work with a4j? If not with a4j, a way to look like a a4j.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another guy who was trying to figure it out at same time as me added a "type=submit" and it worked.

```
<a4j:commandButton type="submit" action="#{someBean.find}" styleClass="bt-find" reRender="someFields"/>
```